# ObjC accessing properties within C function

Tags: objective-c, c, properties

Why can't I access properties of my class from within a C function?
This is what I mean:

[image]

This is my code:

```
@interface MandelGenerator : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate>
{
    //Displays the image
    IBOutlet JSImageView *imageView;
}
@end
```

/

```
#import "MandelGenerator.h"

@implementation MandelGenerator

void test(void) {
    imageView = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you import your class? Posting your whole code would make easier to get some help...

Comment: Yes, I #import the header file where it is declared. I don't understand why it works in the ObjC method, but not the C function.

Comment: As i mentioned above without seeing your code it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't think somethings as mundane as the property declaration would be of significance. Fixed it.

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed it.

Comment: I mean, I added the code, unfortunately I didn't find the solution to the problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C function, unlike the instance method of a class, has no association with an Objective-C class. Just being in the same .m file as the class means nothing -- unlike an instance method, which is called *on* an instance by means of sending a message to it (thus providing the context necessary to know *which* imageView of all the imageViews that might exist as properties of instances of MandelGenerators), a C function isn't called on anything and can only "see" global variables and variables that are passed in to it as parameters. If you want this to work, you would need to change that C method to

```
 void test(MandelGenerator* generator) {
     generator.imageView = nil;
}
```

Assuming that `imageView` is actually a property (it looks like an ivar to me).